# How to sort text by how much it is repeated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, text

I have a text file `abc.txt`, It contains the following lines:

```
a
a
b
c
c
c
d
d
```

I want to sort this list by how much each word is repeated in descending order, in this case it would be:

```
c - 3 times
a - 2 times
d - 2 times
b - 1 time
```

So far, I have read the text file, tried to sort the list but failed using *Python*...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show the code that you have

Comment: @Shresth Pls post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code:

- read lines from file
- count them using collections.Counter which doing the sort for us as well
- show them with the format you requested

```
from collections import Counter


def main():
    file_path = 'abc.txt'

    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().split('\n')

    result = Counter(lines)

    for_show = '\n'.join(f'{key}: {value} item{"s" if value > 1 else ""}' for key, value in result.most_common())

    print(for_show)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be:

```
with open("abc.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
counter = {}
for w in data:
    w = w.strip()
    counter[w]=counter.get(w, 0)+1
sorted_data = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for data in sorted_data:
    print (f'{data[0]}-{data[1]} times')
```

Output:

```
c-3 times
a-2 times
d-2 times
b-1 times
```